# Proving that $t \cos \frac{\pi}{2t}$ is nonrectifiable (Tom Apostol's Calculus vol. $1$, ex $14.13.22$)

Tags: arc-length

The exercise is to show that $f(t) = t \cos \frac{\pi}{2t}$ is not rectifiable.

To show that, Tom Apostol is guiding us to consider the partition $P = \{0, \frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{2n-1}, ..., \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{2}, 1\}$, and to show the corresponding inscribed polygon $\pi(P)$ has length greater than $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{2n}$.

Where did he pull $1$ from?

The only explanation I could get is that he connected the end dots of the polygon, but that's not how he would normally consider an inscribed polygon (e.g. in section $14.10$, and figures $14.12$ or $14.14$).

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the $1$ seems to be an error, but an irrelevant one. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks! Can you please add that as full answer, so I can close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the $1$ seems to be wrong, but it's irrelevant, as we are bounding the length below by a divergent series, regardless.

Comment: Thanks! I just disagree that it's irrelevant, because he states $|\pi(P)| > 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n}$, which means for that particular partition $P$. For posterity, if I'm not mistaken, he wanted to write $|\pi(P)| > \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: I meant, of course, that the $1$ is immaterial in arguing that the curve is non-rectifiable.